# intellij run button is greyed out any fix

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have been having issues when i'm trying to run a skew t plotting project i downloaded from github but when i opened the project in intellij i can't run anything and i have tried to edit the configuration but no luck and i keep getting this error when i open the fxml file that is in the project and the error shows the javafx runtime is not configured either use a JDK that has javafx built in or add a javafx library to the path and i tried javafx sdk version 18 but it kept giving me a not a valid home error
[image: error]
[image: jfx error]
[image: run greyed]

Comment: Please share the screenshot of the whole IDE window.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov i got the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I believe JSF was removed from the JDK in [version 11 and newer](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3261066/javafx-will-be-removed-from-the-java-jdk.html)

You should add it as a [JAR dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.2.20) to your project. Should be easy to do if you use Maven.